# Switching between pics (JFrame, JButton)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I'm trying to make a window that switches between pics when the button "change" is pressed. When I'm trying to run the program, the Java logo pops up like the program is about to start, but then it just disappear. I'm kind of stuck now and I'm hoping that someone can give me a hint about what might be wrong.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageViewer extends JFrame{

private JPanel panel;
private JLabel imageLabel;
private JButton button;
private Icon[] icons = {};
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ImageViewer() {

    try {
        panel = new JPanel();
        URL url1 = new URL("http://www.sm.luth.se/csee/courses/d0010e/l/prob/10tj5Ei9o/LTU-Teatern.jpg");
        URL url2 = new URL("http://www.sm.luth.se/csee/courses/d0010e/l/prob/10tj5Ei9o/LTU-Vetenskapens-hus.jpg");
        Icon image = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(url1));
        Icon image2 = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(url2));
        icons[0] = image;
        icons[1] = image2;
        imageLabel = new JLabel();
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(imageLabel);
        button = new JButton("Change");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
            private boolean value = false;
            {
            }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                value = value == true ? false : true;
                if (value == false) {
                    imageLabel.setIcon(icons[0]);
                }else { 
                    imageLabel.setIcon(icons[1]);
                }
            }
        });
        this.setContentPane(panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new ImageViewer();
}
}
```

Comment: *"I'm kind of stuck now and I'm hoping that someone can give me a hint about what might be wrong."* 1) You forgot to ask a question. 2) You missed two important tags (Java & Swing) so few people have even seen this. 3) `}catch (Exception e) { }`  Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()` 4) BTW - `value = !value;` is shorter and clearer than `value = value == true ? false : true;`

Answer (score 0):

First, here's what I created to give you some hints.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

And here's the code.  The hints will follow after the code.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ImageViewer implements Runnable {

    private boolean isImage1;

    private BufferedImage image;

    private ImageData imageData;

    private JLabel label;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ImageViewer());
    }

    public ImageViewer() {
        this.imageData = new ImageData();
        this.image = imageData.getImage1();
        this.isImage1 = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Viewer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        panel.add(label);

        JButton button = new JButton("Change");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (isImage1) {
                    image = imageData.getImage2();
                } else {
                    image = imageData.getImage1();
                }
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                isImage1 = !isImage1;
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ImageData {

        private BufferedImage image1;
        private BufferedImage image2;

        public ImageData() {
            URL url1;
            URL url2;
            try {
                url1 = new URL("http://www.sm.luth.se/csee/courses/d0010e/l/prob/10tj5Ei9o/LTU-Teatern.jpg");
                url2 = new URL("http://www.sm.luth.se/csee/courses/d0010e/l/prob/10tj5Ei9o/LTU-Vetenskapens-hus.jpg");
                this.image1 = readImage(url1);
                this.image2 = readImage(url2);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private BufferedImage readImage(URL url) {
            try {
                return ImageIO.read(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage1() {
            return image1;
        }

        public BufferedImage getImage2() {
            return image2;
        }

    }
}
```

So here are the hints.

1. Do not extend JFrame, or any Swing component, unless you intend to override one or more of the class methods.
2. Always start your Swing project on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  I implemented Runnable in the main ImageViewer class for convenience.  Your main method should always contain a call to SwingUtilities invokeLater.
3. I moved the reading of the images to its own data class. Always separate the data from the view.  I usually use the model / view / controller architecture to create a Swing project.
4. I checked for errors in the URLs or the actual image reading.  If an error had occurred, it would have printed a stack trace which would have helped me find the error.  Never enclose whole methods in a try-catch block.
5. The only Swing component that needed to be a class variable was the JLabel component.  Only make the class variables that you need for the whole class.  My habit is to make all the class variables private, as well as the class methods.  Only expose the methods that need to be exposed.

Once I did all these things, writing the action listener was trivial.